# how to avoid console network error (host is not communicating) when passwd or update?

Tags: centos6, update, console, passwd, winscp

I am trying to change the root password and update ssl package but the commands `passwd` or `yum update {package}` make the console loops endlessly.
I have set the buffer to 600 sec. which I am reaching everytime, and the console is aborting a few minutes after (network error).

The server distribution is Centos 6.4, I use WinSCP, and my OS is Windows8.

Comment: run 'top' and see what is eating resources.

Comment: error "TERM environment variable not set"

Comment: what does `env | grep TERM` tell ?

Comment: it doesn't say anything, I mean like empty response

Comment: I am trying `grep TERM` and the console is not responding

Comment: in your .bashrc or .bash_profile (whatever you are using on login ,out of these)

`export TERM=vt100` this will ensure a TERM is set , than logout and log back in .

Comment: ok now I got top: failed tty get

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15087/discussion-between-akash-and-tritof).

Comment: It looks I can't, it requires 20 in reputation

Comment: `ln -s /lib/terminfo/d/dumb /usr/share/terminfo/d/dumb`
looks like your termcap db is broken

Comment: I feel something is wrong with the server, but the provider says it is my responsability to manage it... I think I am going to change provider to try. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I have the file but I can't read it, it looks encrypted

Comment: what happens when you type in `ln -s /lib/terminfo/d/dumb /usr/share/terminfo/d/dumb` ?

Comment: ln: creating symbolic link `/usr/share/terminfo/d/dumb': File exists

Comment: `mv /usr/share/terminfo/d/dumb /usr/share/terminfo/d/dumb.ng` than `ln -s /lib/terminfo/d/dumb /usr/share/terminfo/d/dumb`. after this logout and log back in or `source ~/.bashrc` than `env |grep TERM` to make sure term is set.

Comment: `env | grep TERM` => 
TERM=vt100
`top` =>
top: failed tty get

Comment: what is your `runlevel` ?

Comment: the `runlevel` N 3

Comment: the server is a vps supposed to be 2G

Comment: how about any other command, is everything giving same error ?

Comment: not everything, when I `yum list` or `clean` or check any kind of infos, it goes well. It is only these 2 commands (as far as I have used it with my newbie knowledge) that send the console in the sky

Comment: I have tried again updating ssl package, it's loading info, calculate the total size, and then go in a loop

Comment: is it like this, since you got the vps ?

Comment: yes, actually I got 2 of them with the same provider, and the 2 have the same issue, one with centOS 6.4, the other 6.5. The performance is strangely totally different, but that is another problem.

Comment: unless you have much of work done on these, dump it and go to another provider, i have myself used vps alot, however vps fresh install should work out of box it shouldn't be like how it is for you, sorry can't help much

Comment: you have spent enough time with me not to be sorry, thank you very very much. I have learned already a few things thanks to you. I think I'll change provider, it seems to be the solution. One is a dev server so it will be easy, the other more complicated, but anyway... Good weekend man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about the `yum`, but you definitely cannot execute the `passwd` or the `top` from WinSCP.

WinSCP cannot execute commands that require a user input and/or a terminal emulation.

For technical background of the limitations, see:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/remote_command#limitations

When you need a full featured terminal (to execute commands like the `passwd`) for your SFTP sessions, you will find the [*Open in PuTTY* command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/integration_putty#open_putty) useful.